# Progress Bar on Title Bar

Tags: android

I want to draw an spinning wheel on the title bar of the activity when another activity is loading in background. But I don't know how to do that. Please Help me regarding that. Listen I don't want Progress Bar, I want some thing like progress bar on the title bar of the screen, which is running till another activity is loaded or not?...........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the only way to do it is to use your own custom title bar. The best thing to do is to make a title bar layout and just  it in all the other layouts and maybe have a helper class to show and hide the progress bar.

Comment: Your link no longer works...Please next time embed the solution on this site.  Links me your answer worthless